# Is the composition of positive, self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, positive-semidefinite, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A,B$ be self-adjoint, bounded, linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq 0$ and $\langle Bx,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in H$. Does it also hold that $\langle ABx,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in H$?

Comment: The answer is no, but the details depend on whether you're talking about Hilbert spaces over $\Bbb R$ or over $\Bbb C$. Over $\Bbb R$, some care is required in constructing $A,B$ such that $\langle ABx ,x \rangle < 0$.

Comment: In the simplest case, just take $H$ to be a two-dimensional space (either over $\mathbb{C}$ or over $\mathbb{R}$), then take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I mean Hilbert spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and updated the question. I think for $$ to be positive more assumptions are needed, for instance, that $$ and $$ commute. Does it maybe also work, if $A$ is strictly positive?

Comment: @Suim Assuming $A$ is strictly positive does not work, just change $A$ to be $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ in the example. Similarly, assuming both $A$ and $B$ are strictly positive does not work either. As Disintegrating By Parts pointed out  in their answer, this happens if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $A,B$ are positive operators. A positive operator is self-adjoint. So, if $AB \ge 0$, then it is necessary that $(AB)^*=AB$, or $BA=AB$. In that case $AB \ge 0$ because, you may write $A=\sqrt{A}^2$ where $\sqrt{A}$ is the unique positive square root of $A$ that commutes with everything that commutes with $A$. Then you end up with $\sqrt{A}B=B\sqrt{A}$ and
$$
             AB=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}B=\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A} \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Double post! SE must have had a server error as you were submitting your answer.